# Run tomcat with Eclipse on Mac

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, apache, tomcat

I know that this question has already been asked a couple of time but any answers helped me to fixed my own problem. Like I said I am working on OSX Mavericks and I would like to use tomcat with Eclipse JEE. Here is exactly what I did : 
- I downloaded Eclipse JEE for mac. 
- I downloaded Apache 7.0.47 on http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi
- I put my folder in /Library/apache-tomcat-7.0.47 and I created a symbolic link in this same folder that I named tomcat
- I tryied to configure it with Eclipse but when I start the server an error message occur : 
"Port 8080 required by Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost is already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s)."

Do you know which process is using the port 8080 on mac OS and how to kill it ?

- I tried to start the server on another port by changing it in eclipse in port 8081. But still nothing appear on localhost:8081.
- I tried to launch appache with the terminal by typing : "/Library/Tomcat/bin/startup.sh" and still nothing happened, my web browser just tell me : "no data received".

I hope I have been understable and hope somebody could give me an issue.

Comment: Running `sudo lsof -i -P` in the Terminal app will list the ports that processes are using.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried this on Mavericks, but I have used Tomcat 7 with the previous two versions of Eclipse on Lion and Mountain Lion.

• Be sure you are using the correct edition, `Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers` not "Eclipse Standard 4.3.1" or "Eclipse IDE for Java Developers" nor any others. In theory you should be able to add plugins in order to get the equivalent, but that has never worked for me nor for many other folks.

• After downloading Tomcat, run it through the [BatChmod app](http://www.lagentesoft.com/batchmod/), turning on the checkboxes to clear the filesystem meta-data. By default, file permissions will block Tomcat from running on a Mac (in my experience at least).

• Test Tomcat by itself. Drag the "startup.sh" into a Terminal window and press Return to launch. Later drag the "shutdown.sh" into the same window to stop. Point a web browser to this address to see Tomcat's welcome:
`http://localhost:8080/`  
(Tip: You can trash all the .bat files when running on a Mac.)

• No need for symlinks. You should not have to do anything to at all to Tomcat, except the BatChmod. The trick is to configure a new server *within* Eclipse. The goal is to make Eclipse aware of your Tomcat folder. I'm sorry I cannot remember exact steps at the moment. Doing the configuration is not as easy as it should be – nothing in Eclipse is as easy as it should be.

• You may need to start from scratch. Trash Eclipse and all of its config files, settings files, etc., both visible and invisible. Do some googling to discover their locations.

• Beware that you should *not* share the "workspace" folder between versions of Eclipse. Others have advised that major (annual) versions of Eclipse are not completely compatible with their settings, prefs, and such.

• There may be some issues with Java 7 on Mavericks -- you may want to check the Apple Java Developer mailing list.

If you have a choice, considering using other tools instead of Eclipse. Eclipse is arcane and fragile. My first choice would be [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), though you'll need the commercial (not free of cost) version to do web server work. I only used Eclipse because of its plugin for [Vaadin](https://www.vaadin.com/). Another choice is [NetBeans](https://www.netbeans.org) which is easier to setup with Tomcat than Eclipse (and now has a good [plugin for Vaadin](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/50531/vaadin-plug-in-for-netbeans) btw).

Tip: I put Tomcat at the root level of my current user's home folder, just to keep things simple.

Comment: the problem is that when i launch tomcat and i try to load the page localhost:8080 it doesn't work, chrome say no data received ...